I keep getting this ENOTDIR error when trying to create a react app
Whenever I attempt to create a react app in my google drive using npx, I get this error. I've found that this problem is specific to creating it in my google drive folder as creating a new react app in my local downloads folder as well as my onedrive both work.
PS G:\My Drive> npx create-react-app test-app

Creating a new React app in G:\My Drive\test-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code ENOTDIR
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path G:\My Drive\test-app\node_modules\babel-jest\node_modules
npm ERR! errno -4052
npm ERR! ENOTDIR: not a directory, mkdir 'G:\My Drive\test-app\node_modules\babel-jest\node_modules'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\jvilf\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-04-14T23_37_26_820Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting test-app/ from G:\My Drive
Done.

I'm new to this, so I've tried every basic solution and searched online as well, but to no avail.

FYI create-react-app is a dead project. I recommend Vite instead which covers a similar case

This seems more like a Windows filesystem issue than anything else. What sort of drive is G:?

Wdym by create-react-app is a dead project? And G: is the drive letter for my google drive for desktop. I'm using google drive because I want to be able to work on this project across multiple devices, and onedrive only allows 5gb of free space, google drive allows 15gb.

I mean it's unmaintained and has plenty of problems that nobody is going to fix. Do you get the same problem if you use a local disk drive instead?

So far I believe the problem lies where the directory path we use contains a space.
My quick fix was running the commands in a simple directory as suggested by Chat GPT like \Desktop\test and it ran fine with no issues.
I too use Google Drive and although my Google drive path is more complicated, the only similarity between yours and mine is that the first folder in the path contains a space. I don't have permissions to rename the path without spaces to test this though.
In order to test this I created another folder with a space in the name on the desktop: \Desktop\second test. I opened VS code in that folder and ran the commands exactly like before but this time when I got to npm install it immediately failed with the same errors from running them in my Google Drive.
I also used create-react-app and vite@latest and the vite version fails as well but only on the second step where I have to put in the command npm install. So my guess is the problem lies around here when npm install installs all the dependencies for the project. I'm not 100% on how it all works so this is all just a guess.
Update: I only tried to use vite on the new folder with a space and it failed but when I used create-react-app on the folder with the space it installed fine so I have no idea. Maybe the there are different reasons why create-react-app works when vite doesnt, and maybe theres also an issue with the fact the Google Drive uses FAT32 for formatting instead of NTFS.
